# Chat dropdown arrow looks weird

Tags: bug, chat

There's an added bar above the dropdown arrow on posts for me:
[image]

The added arrow only shows up in chrome (I'm in chrome beta). It doesn't show up in Firefox and it doesn't show up on Stack Overflow chats, only the SE 2.0 sites have the arrow issue.

Comment: Is your zoom set to 100%? I've noticed similiar problems in different parts of StackExchange when the zoom is slightly off, like 105% or 95%.

Comment: @vcsjones son of a--I didn't even notice that. It was slightly zoomed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As vcsjones suggested this is a result of the Zoom setting in one's browser. By resetting to default zoom; use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to reset zoom or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+mousewheel to zoom in/out until the arrow is normal.

The chat arrow will turn back to normal once the zoom level is at default.