# The chat is "flickering"

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

I'm sorry to be the bad ambassador but I need to report another thing. I'm not sure this is really a bug or if it's just my browser (Chrome), but I rebooted and nothing changed. I have a MacBook Pro with Lion installed. Chrome is version 18.0.1025.165. If there is a need of some data I forgot, please comment below.

I took a quick vid and made a gif that reproduces **exactly** what I see. If you want to try reproducing it, you should know that I noticed that it doesn't happen *always* so don't get discouraged at the first try. Another thing is that it triggers only if you scroll down the chat even if you reached the bottom, when you do, scroll down another time. This is what I see:

> [image]

Yes, this is very annoying. :(

Comment: Have been seeing this in Chrome a lot lately.  Not sure if your problem is exactly the same, but when this happens I can't scroll the screen up to view older messages.  (Chrome 17.0.963.56 m, Win7)

Comment: @Farray I've definitely seen this too. Chrome (whatever the latest stable version is), Windows 7.

Comment: @Farray Yes it happens to me too. But I think it's just that Chrome version, since I don't use Win.

Comment: It's the new Chat By Candlelight feature.  Don't you feel more relaxed already?

Comment: @AdamDavis Not really. :D

Comment: You're awesome for making a gif of precisely the problem.

Comment: That's the heart of rock n roll, which, I have been informed by a reliable source, is still beatin'.  ***Detroit!***

Comment: Has anyone reproduced this with a *vanilla* Chrome, all extensions disabled?

Comment: @balpha I still have this thing. I suppose it isn't going away considering that red tag.

Comment: Interesting interpretation of that tag. No-repro doesn't mean "I don't care", no-repro doesn't mean I currently have no way to fix this, because I cannot even reproduce it. If I could (and I certainly believe you that this is happening), I'd love to fix this. It's also been more than a month since I asked about extensions, and you still haven't answered, by the way.

Comment: @balpha My comment was a bit ambiguous and unnecessary eheh. I know what that tag means, don't worry. Your question was directed at me? "Anyone" is not my username, by the way. :P I'll add more detail about my configuration now, although I honestly don't know what "vanilla Chrome" is. How do I check that?

Comment: "Vanilla" as in "original", no extensions / user scripts / additional plugins / user styles /etc. installed.

Comment: @Alenanno: It might also be useful to post if you have any extensions enabled (chrome://settings/extensions) and if so, what they are. (and to try reproduce the problem without them enabled, as per [`@`balphas request)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122778/the-chat-is-flickering#comment358043_122778).

Answer (score 3):

Reset your zoom setting as per [this related problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120385/166936). Just hit ctrl 0 inside Chat. I used to get this same problem, it's due to how wonky Browser zoom is with Chat (also wonky in general.)