# How can I embed an animation?

Tags: support, images

In my [answer on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/38326/12279), I tried to embed [this animation](http://www.phy.ntnu.edu.tw/ntnujava/index.php?topic=97.0) but it didn't work. Is there any way to embed an animation in a post?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can embed animated gifs. So, use screen capture software to record the animation and then convert it to an animated `gif` file.

[image: Sample animation.]

Comment: Like I did [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122778/176533). :P

Answer (score 7):

We only support a limited number of things that can be embedded in a post. Java applets aren't one of them, so the best you can do is just link to it.

Comment: And, quite frankly, due to [recent security exploits](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2012/Sep/170) targeting the Java plugin, you shouldn't even have it enabled in the browser to begin with. :/