# Chat intermittently experiences good vibrations

Tags: bug, chat

I'm on Google Chrome (39.0.2171.95 m at the moment) and over the last weeks have experienced vibrations in chat. The kind that make the content move up and down. I can't find a way to reproduce it. It goes away on its own after some time. But still something is making it jump repeatedly for a period of time.

I finally managed to capture it in a gif. It's subtle, but it's there.

> [image: good good good, good vibrations]

Could I please have my chat vibration free?

Note: the rate of movement is faster than shown in the gif. The capture program seems to have missed a couple of them.

Comment: [I presume you don't use zoom, right?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122778/213575)

Comment: Nope @Braiam. But given that it's not a confirmed answer there, I'd say this is a dupe?

Comment: I get this. Sometimes after switching to the tab and trying to scroll up it will try and scroll to the bottom, resulting in vibrations. I think, anyway.

Comment: Does it happen when someone enters/leaves the room. What is your screen size? Is your browser maximzed?

Comment: No clue. 1920x1080. Not sure at that time. @rene.

Comment: Maybe not vibration but [Oscillation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166483/158100)

Comment: I've gotten this two but I'm still not sure if it's a bug in chat or in Chrome. I'm using Chrome 41.